# Create User with Profile and Cover Images using REST API

Tags: rest-api, profiles

I am using WordPress as a backend for a mobile app, I'd like to let users specify profile and cover images when registering with the app. I checked the docs [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#create-a-user), and couldn't find a way to specify image URLs. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to **avatar_urls** https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#schema-meta.

Comment: But that says it's read only. You wouldn't be set a value when registering.

Comment: WordPress does not natively support avatars, apart from Gravatars, which are entirely based on the user's email address. If you're using a plugin to support some other kind of avatar, then how to set that by the REST API would depend on the plugin, and you should direct your question to its author